# Не работает получение пользователя в Discord

Tags: discord, discord.py, sendmessage

Я пытаюсь получить пользователя по `id` и отправить ему сообщение. Но метод `get_user` возвращает объект `LazyUser`  и следовательно сообщение не отправляется. Пользователь есть в друзьях на аккаунте, с которого пытаюсь отправить сообщение.

```
user = client.get_user(id) 
await user.send('hello')
```

Ошибка: `AttributeError: 'LazyUser' object has no attribute 'send'`

**По ответам из сети вот что я пробовала:**

Включить `members` в `intents`:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Использовать `Intents.all()`:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Получить данные пользователя не из кэша:

```
user = await client.fetch_user(478250423078223893)
await user.send("hello world")
```

Ошибка: `AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'fetch_user'`

Ничего из этого не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

`get_user` получает данные о используемом `discord.Client`, то есть о боте.
Насколько мне известно, "получение" пользователя возможно только через `Guild`(сервер). Следующий код "получает" `name`+`discriminator` пользователя по айди и отправляет ему `"Hello"`. Если нужно больше информации, то можно "получить" пользователя через перебор `guild.members`

```py
import discord

token = 'token here'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user.name} ready")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot is False:
        guild = bot.get_guild( ID сервера )
        print(guild.get_member( ID участника ))
        user = guild.get_member( ID участника )
        await user.send("Hello")

bot.run(token)
```